# Wrong 1st Argument Type error

Tags: android, google-signin

Am trying to create a Google sign in login page but stuck with an error. Entire code given below.

The error I get is

> "Wrong 1st argument type: Found 'com.example.sudhakarvijayasarathy.testapp.WelcomeActivity',  required 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity' --- (enableAutoManage android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,    OnConnectionFailed Listener) in Builder cannot be applied to ( com.example.sudhakarvijayasarathy.testapp.WelcomeActivity, OnConnectionFailed Listener)"

```
package com.example.sudhakarvijayasarathy.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentController;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;


public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

//TextView name;

    //Button mWelcomeButton;
    SignInButton button;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;

    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    enter code here
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener( mAuthListener );
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_welcome );

        button = (SignInButton) findViewById( R.id.googlebtn );
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity( new Intent( WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class ) );
                }
            }
        };

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                Toast.makeText( WelcomeActivity.this, "Not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        } )
        .addApi( Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso )
        .build();


        //GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder( GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN )
                .requestIdToken( getString( R.string.default_web_client_id ) )
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

//name = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.name );
//name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        /*mWelcomeButton = findViewById(R.id.WelcomeButton);
        mWelcomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent( WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class) ;
                startActivity(i);
            }*/


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent( mGoogleApiClient );
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent( data );
            if (result.isSuccess()){

                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText( WelcomeActivity.this,"Auth Not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately

                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {


        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText( WelcomeActivity.this,"Auth Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extends your Activity By `FragmentActivity` or a Child of It   i.e `AppCompatActivity`.

```
class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```